# Virtual Environment not working on windows - Django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

After installing Virtual Environment and activating it (Scripts\activate), I ran `pip freeze` to show global installed modules. When I try to install any of the packages, it says they are already installed.

I tried installing virtual environment using `--no-site-packages`, but it didn't help either. It still shows all globally installed packages.

I installed virtualenvwrapper, but it didn't help either.

If I remove `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` from `PYTHONPATH` and run `pip freeze`, it does not show any global packages, and it does not install any packages either. There is no response, it just freezes on "Downloading package".

Comment: check `which pip` to find out the `PATH`

Comment: I ran a "pip show  pip" on command line and I got default pip installation location and not the virtual environment pip location. I thought as soon as I activate virtual env it should take the setting of virtualenv. Why is this happening and how do I fix this? If the path needs to be changed, is that required to be done every time I switch to a different environment? Thanks

Comment: Dono what cause this issue. but the solution is ` set environment variable yourself`

Comment: Thanks for the help :). I will try that but I am still looking for an answer on it so keeping this open.